# pandas library in python unable to read html pages with pandas.read_html() method and showing some exceptions

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and i am unable to read HTML documents in python with pandas and i am getting some exception and this code is run in python IDLE to make it easy to post on stack-overflow.

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
>>> d = pd.read_html('pandasbootcamp.herokuapp.com/')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    d = pd.read_html('pandasbootcamp.herokuapp.com/')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 894, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 840, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("html5lib not found, please install it")
ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it
>>>
```

Comment: `pip install html5lib`, you need that library too, or can use `pip install lxml`

Comment: after you install the library, `d = pd.read_html('pandasbootcamp.herokuapp.com/',flavor='html5lib')` or d = pd.read_html('pandasbootcamp.herokuapp.com/',flavor='lxml') depending on what you install.`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run

```
pip install html5lib
```

or install html5lib with whatever other package manager you prefer